# Telerik Radgrid Header checkbox check

Tags: javascript, checkbox, telerik, telerik-grid

I have radgrid with a template column with a check box in the header and check box in the itemtemplate. In javascript I need to uncheck the check box in the header. No way of accessing it seems to work.

I've tried:

```
masterTableHeader.HeaderRow.cells[0].firstElementChild.checked = false;
$("#checkbox").checked = false;
```

and a bunch of other ways.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var chkBox= $('input[id$="checkbox"]');
chkBox[0].checked = false;
```

works!